# Dlookup after Copy Paste?

Tags: vba, ms-access

Have a real quick question.

I am trying to figure out how to have my dlookup work if someone pastes to the field.
If you enter the pack_number manually this works fine but if someone pastes multiple pack_numbers into column they won't populate.

I've tried to have it update afterupdate on the form as an event but it seems to lock the form.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
Private Sub Pack_Number_AfterUpdate()

Me.Refresh
        Me.Req_High_Retail = DLookup("[Current High Retail]", "InSHighRetailqry", "Pack_Number='" & Pack_Number & "'")

End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe there another character going on paste, have you checked it yet?

Comment: I should clarify. When you paste to the field several records the dlookup isn't working. So if let say I have 12 Pack_Numbers I'm pasting in which will create 12 records in the datasheet the dlookup isn't updating.

Comment: Why are you duplicating [Current High Retail] into another table anyway? True, mass pasting a column of data won't work with control AfterUpdate. Probably have to use some form event to cycle records and save each Req_High_Retail or depend on user to click a button.

Comment: As @June7 said, guess there's no need to replicate the value, you could use Pack_Number as a foreign key to create a reference between two tables, this way you could have any field from `InSHighRetailqry` related to this current table records.

Comment: @June7 thanks for responding! to answer your question the form where my user is entering a pack_number is an entry screen. I was hoping to avoid doing a loop through the record and adding an extra step but if there is no way around it I will. Also just want to note that the InSHighRetailqry is a query not a table.

Comment: Doesn't matter if DLookup searches query or table. This is duplicating a value into another table. Still no reason provided to justify.